# Question about Poisson processes as measures

Tags: probability

So I'm reading a paper about absolute continuity of Poisson processes (or Poisson measures) and I am having trouble with the definition of such processes.

In a textbook I read Poisson processes were defined as point processes with independent increments and Poisson distribution. So they are basically mappings $\eta$ from some probability space $\Omega$  to the space of integer valued nonnegative measures (i.e. counting measures). One can also see them as measures on some space $X$ for a fixed $\omega \in \Omega$, i.e. $\eta(\omega)(.)$ is a measure on $X$.

However in the paper Poisson processes seem to be used as a measure on the space of counting measures. For example the author writes

$$\pi_{\lambda} \{ \xi: \xi(B)=0\}=\exp\{-\lambda(B)\}$$

where $\pi_{\lambda}$ is a Poisson process with intensity measure $\lambda$, $B$ is a measurable subset of $X$ and $\xi$ are counting measures.

So my question is, am I missing something? Is this maybe a short notation for some probability measure on the space of counting measures? should it really read something like

$$P_{\pi_{\lambda}}\{ \omega \in \Omega: \pi_{\lambda}(\omega)(B)=0 \}=\exp\{-\lambda(B)\}?$$

Comment: What textbook and paper were you reading? It would help if you posted a picture of their statements or something to that effect.

Comment: The paper is called "Absolute Continuity of Poisson Random Fields" by Yoichiro Takahashi and can be found here: https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/kyotoms1969/26/4/26_4_629/_pdf The textbook i was reading is called "Lectures on the Poisson Process" by Günter Last and Mathew Penrose. The statment I'm having trouble with is exactly what I posted and in the paper there is no definition of Poisson processes.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$ and a measurable mapping $\eta$ from $\Omega$ to the space of counting measures (on some measurable space $(X.\mathcal X)$); let's call the space of counting measures $Z$. $Z$ is endowed with the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal Z$ generated by the maps $Z:\xi\to\xi(B)$ as $B$ varies over $\mathcal X$. Now suppose that $\Bbb P$ is such that $\eta$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is some $\sigma$-finite measure on $(X,\mathcal X)$. The author's $\pi_\lambda$ is then a probability measure on $(Z,\mathcal Z)$, the image of $\Bbb P$ under the mapping $\eta:\Omega\to Z$. Thus
$$
\pi_\lambda\{\xi\in Z:\xi(B)=0\}=\Bbb P\{\omega\in\Omega: \eta(\omega)(B)=0\}=\exp(-\lambda(B))
$$
for all $B\in\mathcal X$.